# Where is my Grub start menu after upgrade to 22.04?

Tags: boot, grub2, 22.04, ubuntu-mate

I made all upgrades from 16.04 Ubuntu Mate to 22.04 successfully.

From the first upgrade I noticed that I can't see my Grub start menu.

Also I noticed that my system takes longer to startup and first it starts in command line with a prompt to login and then it enters in graphical environment.

Don't know if this is suspicious:

```
sudo cat /var/log/boot.log| grep GRUB
[sudo] password for cent: 
         Starting Record successful boot for GRUB...
[  OK  ] Finished Record successful boot for GRUB.
         Starting GRUB failed boot detection...
[  OK  ] Finished GRUB failed boot detection.
         Starting Record successful boot for GRUB...
[  OK  ] Finished Record successful boot for GRUB.
         Starting GRUB failed boot detection...
[  OK  ] Finished GRUB failed boot detection.
         Starting Record successful boot for GRUB...
[  OK  ] Finished Record successful boot for GRUB.
         Starting GRUB failed boot detection...
[  OK  ] Finished GRUB failed boot detection.
```

I thought that

```
sudo update-grub
```

would solve the problem but...it didn't!

Any ideas?

PS: this is not a dual boot system.

In case one needs this:

```
sudo cat /etc/default/grub
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Partitions:

```
sudo parted -l 
Model: ATA WDC WD3200BEKT-7 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 320GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  40,0GB  40,0GB  primary   ext4            boot
 2      40,0GB  315GB   275GB   primary   ext4
 3      315GB   320GB   4999MB  extended
 5      315GB   320GB   4999MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)
```

Comment: Post output of *sudo parted -l* into question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden` to `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu`
Then run

```
sudo update-grub
```

From info grub

```
'GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE'
     If this option is unset or set to 'menu', then GRUB will display
     the menu and then wait for the timeout set by 'GRUB_TIMEOUT' to
     expire before booting the default entry.  Pressing a key interrupts
     the timeout.
```

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you. Also, I read that if someone presses Esc key during startup the menu will appear whatever the settings! https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters

Comment: online grub manual https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html