# Kubuntu 22.10 - no grub menu

Tags: grub2, kubuntu, multiple-monitors

I have installed Kubuntu 22.10 on an old Acer laptop and a no-name desktop. Neither are showing a grub menu on startup so I can't get to safe mode or a command shell to solve a display problem. I've run update-grub2 and it finds the boots (this is the desktop but the laptop is the same):

```
sudo update-grub2
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.19.0-31-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.19.0-31-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.19.0-21-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.19.0-21-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Warning: os-prober will not be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Systems on them will not be added to the GRUB boot configuration.
Check GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER documentation entry.
done
```

I have LG 1360x728 monitor and a Dell 1280x1024 displays on the desktop and the boot fails with an error on the display configuration. *On both screens*. I managed to run the installer in safe graphics mode but when I rebooted I got the display configuration error. I have a workaround which involves unplugging the LG, booting to the 1280x1024, plugging the LG back in and running xrandr to create the 1360x728 resolution, adding it to the display and activating it. I thought that installing the driver from the nvidia site might be an answer but I can't get past the install without errors.

I've tried adding an autostart shell script to do the xrandr but the boot seems to be blocked by the

hwinfo output and system info attached:

```
hwinfo --gfxcard
09: PCI 200.0: 0300 VGA compatible controller (VGA)             
  [Created at pci.386]
  Unique ID: B35A.uQZs1o+xM28
  Parent ID: H0_h.4N97gW8nvQ8
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:06.0/0000:02:00.0
  SysFS BusID: 0000:02:00.0
  Hardware Class: graphics card
  Model: "nVidia GT218 [NVS 300]"
  Vendor: pci 0x10de "nVidia Corporation"
  Device: pci 0x10d8 "GT218 [NVS 300]"
  SubVendor: pci 0x10de "nVidia Corporation"
  SubDevice: pci 0x0863 
  Revision: 0xa2
  Driver: "nouveau"
  Driver Modules: "nouveau"
  Memory Range: 0xfd000000-0xfdffffff (rw,non-prefetchable)
  Memory Range: 0xf8000000-0xfbffffff (ro,non-prefetchable)
  Memory Range: 0xf6000000-0xf7ffffff (ro,non-prefetchable)
  I/O Ports: 0xe800-0xe87f (rw)
  Memory Range: 0x000c0000-0x000dffff (rw,non-prefetchable,disabled)
  IRQ: 27 (782611 events)
  Module Alias: "pci:v000010DEd000010D8sv000010DEsd00000863bc03sc00i00"
  Driver Info #0:
    Driver Status: nvidiafb is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe nvidiafb"
  Driver Info #1:
    Driver Status: nouveau is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe nouveau"
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
  Attached to: #21 (PCI bridge)

Primary display adapter: #9
```

I'm at the point of retiring the LG and looking for a new second monitor unless you have any suggestions...

Comment: For grub menu https://askubuntu.com/questions/1441582/where-is-my-grub-start-menu-after-upgrade-to-22-04/1441641#1441641

Comment: Thanks for that. Fixed.